# How to delegate permission to Mark OU Object as "Protected from Accidental Deletion"

Tags: active-directory, security, windows-server-2012-r2, delegation, organizational-unit

I have created a new OU and delegated its permissions to multiple personnel; unfortunately, when they create a new OU underneath the previous one, the checkbox of "Protect from Accidental Deletion" is greyed out. How to enabled it via delegation for every new OU created?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, you can add a rule on the parent OU ("Deny" on "this object only" to "Everyone" the rights "DeleteChild, DeleteTree, Delete"). Then the "Protect from Accidental Deletion" control should not be greyed anymore on the sub-OU for delegates